# PHP: What is the best way to mark items in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

If I want certain entries in an array to by manually marked (highlighting particular entries in the database as necessary) so that they can be detected and thus treated differently. I'm wondering what the ideal way to do this is? ie the quickest (performance-wise) and most efficient. Currently I'm doing it like this:

Array:

```
"A"=>"yes",
"B"=>"no >",
"C"=>"why",
```

The code detects it like this:

```
if (strpos($string,' >')!==false) {//action//}
```

So as you can see its detecting the entry that I manually added a `>` to. But its annoying too because then the character has to be removed with a `str_replace`.

Comment: Why not store the index of selected items in a different array?  If in a relational database, you shouldn't change the value to indicate something is selected, you should have a separate column indicating something is selected.

Comment: ^ with http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: You appear to mix the concepts of an array and of a database. In the database such information definitely should be kept in a separate table, for the array inside the script logic it might make sense to have a second array holding that additional tables information.

Comment: What would be stored in a separate array? The whole entry ie "B"=>"no"  ?

Comment: Are you sure its better to add whole other array database with all these marked whole entries rather than just add a  " >" to each item? Just want to be sure.

Comment: @Hasen, are you sure you actually have two elements with identical keys (`'B'`) in one array?!? This is not possible.

Comment: @cars10m I expect this is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of answers.

Question:

```
$array = [
    "A" => "yes"
    "B" => "no" //this is the correct result.
    "C" => "why"
]

$answer = [
    0 => "B"; 
]
```

And run some comparison logic; foreach value of the array check it against the correct answer:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
   if(in_array($key, $answer)){
       // this is the correct answer. So process.
       $correct = "The correct answer is ".$key." : '".$value."'"; 
   }
}
unset($key,$value);

 print $correct; // "The correct answer is B : 'no'"
```

Comment: Ok looks nice, can you explain why it is better like this though? It would seem it would take longer to mark an item each time for example. Adding a new entry 0 => "B" rather than just adding a > on the end right where the entry is.

Comment: You have one or multiple array of questions and one array of answers. Where they match it's a match! I assume you have more than one question, so this can apply across the board